# can the = default specifier be used other than constructors?

Tags: c++

I know that the = delete specifier can be used for normal functions as well like:

```
void foo(int)
{
}
void foo(double) = delete;
```

Similarly, can the default specifier also be used in functions?

Comment: What would `void foo(int) = default;` even mean?  What would the default do?

Comment: See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/default).

Comment: Even though simply trying can be inadaquate as a test with C++ sometimes... did you try?

Comment: You could simply try compiling code that uses it, and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

The `default` specifier means "let the compiler generate a 'default' one for me". There's no rule for a compiler to generate a "default `foo()` function", so the `= default` specifier will not work for that. (In fact, how do you expect such a default to make sense?)

Only the following 6 functions that *can* be default-generated accept the `= default` specifier:

- Default constructor
- Destructor (`Foo::~Foo()`)
- Copy constructor
- Copy assignment operator (`Foo& operator=(const Foo&)`)
- Move constructor
- Move assignment operator (`Foo& operator=(Foo&&)`)

Starting from C++20, 7 comparison functions [also accept the `= default` specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons). They're in the form of:

- `bool operator op(const Other &);`, where `op` is one of `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, `==`, `!=`.
- [The spaceship operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons#Custom_comparisons_and_comparison_categories) `operator <=> (const Other &)`

Answer (score 2):

Other than constructors and assignment operators, you can also use `default` for all of the comparison functions.  This applies to member functions and friend functions.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Really?  [This](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.compare.default#1) seems to imply it applies to all comparison operator

Comment: @cigien - Last I checked the proposal was mentioning `<=>` and `==` only. I'll also be weary of quoting the draft HEAD. I'll see if something more refined is in n4861.

Comment: Ah... Waddaya know. https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.fct.def.default#1.1 and https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.binary#2.sentence-4 - I guess my hash of the standard was out of date.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Also [the proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0515r3.pdf) asks for all of the operators.

Comment: Okay, this isn't what I read at all. Now I'm wondering which paper it was. Oh well.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica it could be one one of "incomplet and incorrekt" ones.

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

No.

## Long answer

> Special member functions along with the comparison operators (since
> C++20) are the only functions that can be defaulted, that is, defined
> using = default instead of the function body

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#Special_member_functions